# incompatible types: ArrayList<Entry> cannot be converted to List<PieEntry>

Tags: java, android, arraylist, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I would like to make an application with PieChart.
And I made two application. In one everything is correct. But if I copy code to the second one, I have got

```
Error:(95, 48) error: incompatible types: ArrayList<Entry> cannot be converted to List<PieEntry>
```

This is my code from mainActivity in working application:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    float zmienna = 123;
    private static String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private float[] yData = {zmienna, 10.6f, 66.76f, 44.32f, 46.01f, 16.89f, 23.9f};

    PieChart pieChart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starting to create chart");

        pieChart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.graph);

        pieChart.setRotationEnabled(true);
        pieChart.setHoleRadius(25f);
        pieChart.setTransparentCircleAlpha(0);

        pieChart.setCenterTextSize(10);

        addDataSet();

    }

    private void addDataSet() {
        Log.d(TAG, "addDataSet started");
        ArrayList<PieEntry> yEntrys = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < yData.length; i++){
            yEntrys.add(new PieEntry(yData[i] , i));
        }

        //create the data set
        PieDataSet pieDataSet = new PieDataSet(yEntrys, "Employee Sales");
        pieDataSet.setSliceSpace(2);
        pieDataSet.setValueTextSize(12);

        //create pie data object
        PieData pieData = new PieData(pieDataSet);
        pieChart.setData(pieData);
        pieChart.invalidate();
    }
}
```

On the second application code is the same. But error is in line

```
PieDataSet pieDataSet = new PieDataSet(yEntrys, "Employee Sales");
```

And write:

```
Error:(95, 48) error: incompatible types: ArrayList<Entry> cannot be converted to List<PieEntry>
```

Please, help
Because I don't really know. What is going on with this two application.

Comment: Can you show us which one line 95 is?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265) but it's hard to tell at the moment.

Comment: PieDataSet pieDataSet = new PieDataSet(yEntrys, "Employee Sales");

Comment: Yes, but before it. it's incompatibile types. Mayby the reason is that, because in this second application I've got much more code. But this one method which is for PieChar is the same?

Comment: I tried this one. But next I've got problem this PieData pieData = new PieData(pieDataSet);

Comment: If you want someone to find an error for you, it's best if you post the code WITH the error.  It makes no sense to post code that actually works, and expect us to find a bug in it.

Comment: @DavidWallace Removed and thanks for the hint...always used it like that.

Comment: OK, thanks for information, it was my first post on stackoverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed the code block is a working code block.

The issue you're having 'On the second application' is

The `yEntrys` is of type `ArrayList<Entry>` when it's expecting `List<PieEntry>`. Try changing yEntries to `ArrayList<PieEntry> yEntrys = new ArrayList<>();` in the second application and that should fix your issue.

Also see the [docs](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Data) for more info.

If not please post the not working Activity

Comment: Oh, I didn't spot that he'd posted the code WITHOUT the error, instead of the code WITH the error.  Well done.

Comment: The problem in this second application is PieDataSet
(java.util.List<com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry>,
String)
in PieDataSet cannot be applied
to
(java.util.List<com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieEntry>,
String)

Answer (score 0):

You could change the constructor for `PieDataSet` so that the first parameter is of type `List<? extends Entry>` instead of `List<Entry>`.

If you do that, you'll be able to pass an `ArrayList<Entry>` or an `ArrayList<PieEntry>` to it, and both versions of your application will work.  I am, of course, assuming that `PieEntry` is a subtype of `Entry`.

Comment: I think the problem is not with the List but with the PieDataSet
(java.util.List<com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry>,
String)
in PieDataSet cannot be applied
to
(java.util.List<com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieEntry>,
String)

Comment: Yup.  That's why I said "change the constructor for `PieDataSet`"

Comment: but I'm still dont understand why, in one appication this code works correct, but in second I've got problem with it. Everything is the same. And application don't be connected with each other

Comment: Well, an `ArrayList <Entry>` and an `ArrayList <PieEntry>` are really not the same thing. You can't use one in place of the other.